# command to delete all files with numbers

Tags: grep, rm

How can I delete nay file that has a number in its name from directory /www/ and up?
Like, it would delete

a1.php

a2.php

123213.php

asdasd5.php

Would this work?

`ls | grep \([1-9]\) -f | xargs rm`

I haven't tested it yet, don't want to mess up anything.

Comment: I suggest you create a test folder and chuck some test files into the folder.

Comment: this question belongs on Unix.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use find. Something like:

> find /www/ -name "*[0-9]*" -type f -exec rm {} \;

This will find all the files only (*-type f*) in /www with at least one number in the filename and execute *rm FILE* on it.

Out of safety try it first out with echo, such as:

> find /www/ -name "*[0-9]*" -type f -exec echo {} \;

Comment: Stars are needed around the `[0-9]` as in `*[0-9]*`

Comment: Absolutely! I'm sorry the stars were there but they weren't escaped with the slash so they weren't displayed correctly :( I'm sorry, now i corrected.